# How to limit Python to work only with integers?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import math

# I define a function that will calculate the log

def shank(a,p,z):
    x=math.log(p,a)%z

    return (x)

print("First log")
print(shank(106, 12375, 24691))


print("Second log")
print(shank(6, 248388, 458009))
```

I get correct answers, but it doesn't give me integers. For example if I input

```
print(shank(3, 525, 809))
```

I get 5.701190790597276, while 309 also works and would be the answer I prefer.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate discrete logarithms? `math.log(p, a) % z` is not a discrete logarithm.

Comment: You should give a proper description of what you're trying to do, even though it looks like more of a mathematical problem than a programming problem.

Comment: The answer of `math.log(p,a)` returns a float, so I don't know why you would expect an integer.

Comment: @user2357112 that is what I am trying to do. I was trying to figure out if I can write a simple function to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`math.log(p, a) % z` is not a discrete logarithm. This expression tells Python to compute a regular logarithm, divide it by `z`, and give you the remainder. If you could somehow limit Python to work only with integers, you still wouldn't get a discrete logarithm; you would get an exception when Python finds that `math.log(p, a)` does not have an integer solution.

Python doesn't come with a built-in discrete logarithm routine. Computing discrete logarithms efficiently is one of the famous unsolved problems of computer science, and many cryptographic systems rely on it being hard. That said, if you're okay with a painfully slow solution, you can just compute higher and higher modular powers until you find one that works:

```
def discrete_log(base, target, modulus):
    i = 0
    power = 1
    while power != target:
        power = (power * base) % modulus
        i += 1
    return i
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I do realise that with really big numbers I would need to use other techniques than just straight calculation, I was just trying to get a basic function for smaller numbers